# libopencv_gpu.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gpu

I'm trying to compile that code (houghlines.cpp from gpu samples):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::gpu;

static void help()
{
    cout << "This program demonstrates line finding with the Hough transform." << endl;
    cout << "Usage:" << endl;
    cout << "./gpu-example-houghlines <image_name>, Default is pic1.png\n" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    const string filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : "~/Images/skorn00.png";

    Mat src = imread(filename, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (src.empty())
    {
        help();
        cout << "can not open " << filename << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat mask;
    Canny(src, mask, 100, 200, 3);

    Mat dst_cpu;
    cvtColor(mask, dst_cpu, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    Mat dst_gpu = dst_cpu.clone();

    vector<Vec4i> lines_cpu;
    {
        const int64 start = getTickCount();

        HoughLinesP(mask, lines_cpu, 1, CV_PI / 180, 50, 60, 5);

        const double timeSec = (getTickCount() - start) / getTickFrequency();
        cout << "CPU Time : " << timeSec * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
        cout << "CPU Found : " << lines_cpu.size() << endl;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines_cpu.size(); ++i)
    {
        Vec4i l = lines_cpu[i];
        line(dst_cpu, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    GpuMat d_src(mask);
    GpuMat d_lines;
    HoughLinesBuf d_buf;
    {
        const int64 start = getTickCount();

        gpu::HoughLinesP(d_src, d_lines, d_buf, 1.0f, (float) (CV_PI / 180.0f), 50, 5);

        const double timeSec = (getTickCount() - start) / getTickFrequency();
        cout << "GPU Time : " << timeSec * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
        cout << "GPU Found : " << d_lines.cols << endl;
    }
    vector<Vec4i> lines_gpu;
    if (!d_lines.empty())
    {
        lines_gpu.resize(d_lines.cols);
        Mat h_lines(1, d_lines.cols, CV_32SC4, &lines_gpu[0]);
        d_lines.download(h_lines);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines_gpu.size(); ++i)
    {
        Vec4i l = lines_gpu[i];
        line(dst_gpu, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    imshow("source", src);
    imshow("detected lines [CPU]", dst_cpu);
    imshow("detected lines [GPU]", dst_gpu);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

But after running i get this message (excution):
/workspace/test_opencv/test_opencv/bin/Release/test_opencv: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_gpu.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Here is the build :
-------------- Build: Release in test_gpu (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -O2    -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv  -c /home/thomas/workspace/test_opencv/test_gpu/main.cpp -o obj/Release/main.o
g++ -L/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/include/opencv  -o bin/Release/test_gpu obj/Release/main.o   -s  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so 
Output size is 14,44 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds)

The houghines.cpp from cpu samples work well. It seems it comes from libopen_gpu library compilation.
CMAKE doesn't return error when i compile opencv WITH_CUDA.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it is what i have been expected:
I add in the source file:
`cv::gpu::printShortCudaDeviceInfo(cv::gpu::getDevice());`

And it returned:

`OpenCV Error: No GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in getDevice, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp, line 182
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:182: error: (-216) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function getDevice`

Now I have to compile opencv with cuda (CMAKE). But i have ever done this part...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the same issue as here: [openCV program compile error "libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" in ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335848/opencv-program-compile-error-libopencv-core-so-2-4-cannot-open-shared-object-f) , configure everything properly and it should run.

Comment: As mentionned above build log return the path location of lib. So it seems it is good because all other lib work well. So it comes from load gpu lib from opencv.