# Can't find libopecv_core.so.2.3, file actually not there

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu

So I have a question concerning a .so file in Ubuntu.  I'm trying to run a program in QT creator, but I get the error

```
/home/sean/Desktop/iStrabGUI_140321/iStrabGUI: error while loading 
shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.3: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My opencv and opencv2 directories are located at /usr/include, and I did add them to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.  However, after checking inside the opencv and opencv2 directories, it doesn't seem like the file is there at all.  My question is, how do I go about getting this file?  I've already installed libopencv-dev on my computer, so where does this come from?

Comment: This could help you out, it's quite similar to your problem: [openCV program compile error “libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory” in ubuntu 12.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335848/opencv-program-compile-error-libopencv-core-so-2-4-cannot-open-shared-object-f)

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the comment.  I've tried the solutions detailed in the post you referred me to, but I had the same problem.  I've tried looking for the files on my machine, but I have been unable to find them.  I think that might be part of what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* can not find the shared library, it seems to me that you have not installed openCV properly. You might have downloaded openCV but not built the libraries, I assume?

Since you are using Ubuntu you can install openCV from the Ubuntu repository
`sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv`

Comment: Thank you.  I did some tinkering and it turns out you're right.  I had to reinstall opencv.  Thanks!