# I Cant Run Opencv Project in other machines

Tags: linux, eclipse, opencv, software-distribution

I have a project whit opencv on my machine that is running ok, it works and does what it should do. In my machine I installed the opencv libraries. The problem is that when I want to run the program on another Linux machine I get this error:

```
Error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.3.1
```

My question is, exist some way to compile the proyect and work in any machine with linux? whitout reinstall opencv libraries in those machine
How should I configure eclipse for packge all project?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

[image: img5]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335848/opencv-program-compile-error-libopencv-core-so-2-4-cannot-open-shared-object-f)?

Comment: Hi, mmm I'v not tried. I need know if possible package all inside of a folder and not install libraries out of the program