# Linker Error on a simple OpenCV program in an alpine docker container

Tags: c++, docker, opencv, alpine-linux

I have a simple program that shows an image.

```
    String imagePath = "D:/Dev Tools/Docker/alpineOpenCV/";
    Mat img = imread(imagePath+"lena.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    imshow ("Test Image", img);
```

And I have an image built using the following dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine:3.9
RUN echo -e '@edgunity http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community\n\
@edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main\n\
@testing http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing\n\
@community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community'\
  >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk add --update \
  # --virtual .build-deps \
      build-base \
      openblas-dev \
      unzip \
      wget \
      cmake \
      libtbb@testing  \
      libtbb-dev@testing   \
      libjpeg  \
      libjpeg-turbo-dev \
      libpng-dev \
      jasper-dev \
      tiff-dev \
      libwebp-dev \
      clang-dev \
      linux-headers 

ENV CC /usr/bin/clang
ENV CXX /usr/bin/clang++

ENV OPENCV_VERSION=4.0.1
RUN cd /opt && \
  wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip && \
  unzip ${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip && \
  rm -rf ${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip

RUN mkdir -p /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}/build && \
  cd /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}/build && \
  cmake \
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
  -D WITH_FFMPEG=NO \
  -D WITH_IPP=NO \
  -D WITH_OPENEXR=NO \
  -D WITH_TBB=YES \
  -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=NO \
  -D BUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=NO \
  -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=NO \
  -D BUILD_DOCS=NO \
  -D BUILD_opencv_python2=NO \
  -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
  -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python \
  -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include/python3.6m/ \
  -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libpython3.so \
  -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libpython3.so \
  -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ \
  -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/ \
  .. && \
  make VERBOSE=1 && \
  make && \
  make install && \
  rm -rf /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}
```

I can compile my program successfully using:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ -L/usr/local/lib64/ -g -o binary  main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lop
encv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_imgcodecs
```

However I get linker errors when trying to run `./binary`

```
Error loading shared library libopencv_core.so.4.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./binary2)
Error loading shared library libopencv_highgui.so.4.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./binary2)
Error loading shared library libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./binary2)
Error relocating ./binary2: _ZN2cv8fastFreeEPv: symbol not found
Error relocating ./binary2: _ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEi: symbol not found
Error relocating ./binary2: _ZN2cv6imshowERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_11_InputArrayE: symbol not found
Error relocating ./binary2: _ZN2cv7waitKeyEi: symbol not found
Error relocating ./binary2: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv: symbol not found
```

I have tried the following solutions in this [this thread:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335848/opencv-program-compile-error-libopencv-core-so-2-4-cannot-open-shared-object-f) to no avail. I can see that my so files are in `/usr/local/lib64/` but I cannot seem to link them properly.

**UPDATE: ldd ./binary output**

```
/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f13f91db000)
        libopencv_core.so.4.0 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.0 (0x7f13f8d33000)
        libopencv_highgui.so.4.0 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0 (0x7f13f8d24000)
        libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0 (0x7f13f8cdb000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7f13f8b86000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7f13f8b72000)
        libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f13f91db000)
        libtbb.so.2 => /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2 (0x7f13f893d000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7f13f8923000)
        libopenblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libopenblas.so.3 (0x7f13f6da6000)
        libopencv_videoio.so.4.0 => /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0 (0x7f13f6d70000)
        libopencv_imgproc.so.4.0 => /usr/local/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.0 (0x7f13f689c000)
        libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.8 (0x7f13f683b000)
        libwebp.so.7 => /usr/lib/libwebp.so.7 (0x7f13f67e5000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/libpng16.so.16 (0x7f13f67b5000)
        libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/libtiff.so.5 (0x7f13f674b000)
        libjasper.so.4 => /usr/lib/libjasper.so.4 (0x7f13f66da000)
        libgfortran.so.5 => /usr/lib/libgfortran.so.5 (0x7f13f6547000)
        libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/../lib/libquadmath.so.0 (0x7f13f6514000)
```

Comment: The simplies way - using CMake and FindPackage(OpenCV) for your project

Comment: Could you post the output of `ldd ./binary`?

Comment: just posted it. This was after moving the files from `lib64` to `lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying so many times and rebuilding for so many hours. I just went and copied all the files from `/usr/local/lib64/` to `/usr/local/lib/`. It may not be elegant. But it works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need `RUN ldconfig` or `ENV PATH="/usr/local/lib64:${PATH}"` at the end of you docker runfile.

Comment: It might take a while I'll post an update once done.