# No rule to make target libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2.0 but opencv 3.4.1 installed, when making ROS workspace

Tags: opencv, ros, catkin

I have opencv 3.4.1 installed from source on my ubuntu. But when running command catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release I get error:

No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2.0', needed by '~/ros_ws/devel/lib/stereo_slam/image_handle_node'.  Stop.
No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2.0', needed by '~/ros_ws/devel/lib/libmetrics_lib.so'.  Stop.

I've already tried following this: [openCV program compile error "libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" in ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335848/opencv-program-compile-error-libopencv-core-so-2-4-cannot-open-shared-object-f)

[EDIT] I get the same error compiling using clion or catkin_make directly from terminal, but clion creates special packages for release and debug versions. I don't quite understand these packages but in files CMakeCache.txt i found folowing lines:

```
//Dependencies for the target
metrics_lib_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libtf.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libtf2_ros.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libactionlib.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libmessage_filters.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libtf2.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libcv_bridge.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libimage_geometry.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_shape.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_viz.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_aruco.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bgsegm.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bioinspired.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ccalib.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_datasets.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_dpm.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_face.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_freetype.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_fuzzy.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_hdf.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_line_descriptor.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_optflow.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_plot.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_reg.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_rgbd.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_saliency.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stereo.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_structured_light.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_surface_matching.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_text.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ximgproc.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xobjdetect.so.3.2.0;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xphoto.so.3.2.0;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libroscpp.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_signals.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/librosconsole.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/librostime.so;general;/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libcpp_common.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so.0.4;general;prometheus-cpp::core;general;prometheus-cpp::pull;general;ceres;general;proto;
```

I don't understand what these metrics_lib_LIB_DEPENDS are, and from where do they come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that I uninstalled previous version of opencv via next command:

```
sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

By doing this I also erased the contents of the ROS OpenCV library. Later even after reinstalling ROS, these libraries did not reinstall because the system thinks they are installed but nothing was in them. I had to apt-get each library individually.

Don't purge OpenCV...

Answer (score 2):

I also used erroneously `sudo find / -name "opencv" -exec rm -i {} \;` to remove opencv and I had the same problem. 
I solved with :

```
sudo apt remove libopencv-dev   
sudo apt remove libopencv-core3.2
```

However not all the opencv lib will be unistalled with this, so you need to remove all the opencv lib installed with ros (in my case I needed to remove also `opencv-data`). You can find them with:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep opencv
```

after that you can install again ros melodic (or whatever you are using) :

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```